# Remove Termux's extra keys

Tags: termux

I can reduce the extra keys on Termux to one row like this:

```
extra-keys = [[ESC, TAB, CTRL, ALT, {key: '-', popup: '|'}, DOWN, UP]]
```

but this doesn't get rid of them:

```
extra-keys-style = none
```

How do I get rid of Termux's extra keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add the following line to the `~/.termux/termux.properties` file:

```
extra-keys = []
```

apply the changes by running (or restart Termux):

```
termux-reload-settings
```